# How do I group dataframe columns based on their sequence relation

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am trying to group based on their sequence relationship beween the two columns.

```
d = {'df1':[10,20, 30, 60, 70, 40, 30, 70], 'df2':[20, 30, 40, 80, 70, 50, 90, 100]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df

   df1  df2
0   10  20
1   20  30
2   30  40
3   60  80
4   80  70
5   40  50
6   30  90
7   70  100
```

I am expecting the result something below:

To make it more clear:- df1 and df2 have a relationship based on their sequence. For example, 10 has a direct relation with 20 and 10 has an indirect relation with 30 through 20. And also 10 has an indirect relation with 40 through 20 and 30. An additional example, let us take 80 has a direct relation with 70 and indirect relation with 100 through 70. This works for the rest of the column values.

```
  df1  |    df2
  -----|-------------------
0   10 | 20, 30, 40, 50, 90
1   20 | 30, 40, 50, 90
2   30 | 40, 50, 90
3   60 | 80, 70, 100
4   80 | 70, 100
5   40 | 50
6   70 | 100
```

I am trying using the script below but I couldn't succeed.

```
(df.groupby('df1')
   .agg({ 'df2' : ','.join})
   .reset_index()
   .reindex(columns=df.columns))
```

Could anyone help on this challenge? If there is any similar solution here at **Stack overflow** kindly let me know.

**Edit:**
The first answer works perfectly with the above example but when I try with the data that I want to do it doesn't work correctly. my real data look like below.

```
    df1 df2
0   10  20
1   10  30
2   10  80
3   10  90
4   10  120
5   10  140
6   10  170
7   20  180
8   30  40
9   30  165
10  30  175
11  40  20
12  40  50
13  50  60
14  60  70
15  70  180
16  80  180
17  90  100
18  100 110
19  110 180
20  120 130
21  130 180
22  140 150
23  150 160
24  160 165
25  165 180
26  165 200
27  170 175
28  175 180
29  175 200
30  180 190
31  190 200
32  200 210
33  210 220
34  220 230
35  230 240
36  240 -
```

Comment: Hi could you clarify the relationship between the columns that you want to group by?

Comment: Hi Eva, Thank you for your reply. df1 and df2 have a relationship based on their sequence. For example, 10 has a direct relation with 20 and 10 has an indirect relation with 30 through 20. And also 10 has an indirect relation with 40 through 20 and 30. 
An additional example, let us take 80 has a direct relation with 70 and indirect relation with 100 through 70. This works for the rest of the column values.

Comment: Why is there 90 in the sequence in the first row? There is no 50 in the first column so the sequence should end right there. Maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: @treskov Thank you for the reply. As you see on index number 6, 30 has a direct relation with 90. and we know that 10 has an indirect relation with 30 through 20. So that 10 has an indirect relation with 90 through 30. We could say this a kind of transitive property but it is more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

l1 = [10, 20, 30, 60, 80, 40, 30, 70]
l2 = [20, 30, 40, 80, 70, 50, 90, 100]

d = dict()
for i, j in zip(l1, l2):
    if i == j:
        continue
    d.setdefault(i, []).append(j)

for k in d:
    d[k].extend(chain.from_iterable(d.get(v, []) for v in d[k]))

df = pd.DataFrame({'df1': list(d.keys()), 'df2': [', '.join(str(v) for v in d[k]) for k in d]})
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   df1                 df2
0   10  20, 30, 40, 90, 50
1   20      30, 40, 90, 50
2   30          40, 90, 50
3   60         80, 70, 100
4   80             70, 100
5   40                  50
6   70                 100
```

---

EDIT: Other solution based on new input data. Now I'm checking for possible circles in the path:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''
0   10  20
1   10  30
2   10  80
3   10  90
4   10  120
5   10  140
6   10  170
7   20  180
8   30  40
9   30  165
10  30  175
11  40  20
12  40  50
13  50  60
14  60  70
15  70  180
16  80  180
17  90  100
18  100 110
19  110 180
20  120 130
21  130 180
22  140 150
23  150 160
24  160 165
25  165 180
26  165 200
27  170 175
28  175 180
29  175 200
30  180 190
31  190 200
32  200 210
33  210 220
34  220 230
35  230 240
36  240 -
'''

df1, df2 = [], []
for line in data.splitlines()[:-1]: # <--- get rid of last `-` character
    line = line.strip().split()
    if not line:
        continue

    df1.append(int(line[1]))
    df2.append(int(line[2]))

from pprint import pprint

d = dict()
for i, j in zip(df1, df2):
    if i == j:
        continue
    d.setdefault(i, []).append(j)

for k in d:
    seen = set()
    for v in d[k]:
        for val in d.get(v, []):
            if val not in seen:
                seen.add(val)
                d[k].append(val)


df = pd.DataFrame({'df1': list(d.keys()), 'df2': [', '.join(str(v) for v in d[k]) for k in d]})
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    df1                                                df2
0    10  20, 30, 80, 90, 120, 140, 170, 180, 40, 165, 1...
1    20                  180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240
2    30  40, 165, 175, 20, 50, 180, 200, 190, 210, 220,...
3    40  20, 50, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240, 60, 70
4    50          60, 70, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240
5    60              70, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240
6    70                  180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240
7    80                  180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240
8    90        100, 110, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240
9   100             110, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240
10  110                  180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240
11  120             130, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240
12  130                  180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240
13  140   150, 160, 165, 180, 200, 190, 210, 220, 230, 240
14  150        160, 165, 180, 200, 190, 210, 220, 230, 240
15  160             165, 180, 200, 190, 210, 220, 230, 240
16  165             180, 200, 190, 210, 200, 220, 230, 240
17  170             175, 180, 200, 190, 210, 220, 230, 240
18  175             180, 200, 190, 210, 200, 220, 230, 240
19  180                       190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240
20  190                            200, 210, 220, 230, 240
21  200                                 210, 220, 230, 240
22  210                                      220, 230, 240
23  220                                           230, 240
24  230                                                240
```

Or `pprint(d, width=250)` :

```
{10: [20, 30, 80, 90, 120, 140, 170, 180, 40, 165, 175, 100, 130, 150, 190, 20, 50, 200, 110, 160, 60, 210, 70, 220, 230, 240],
 20: [180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240],
 30: [40, 165, 175, 20, 50, 180, 200, 190, 210, 220, 230, 240, 60, 70],
 40: [20, 50, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240, 60, 70],
 50: [60, 70, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240],
 60: [70, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240],
 70: [180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240],
 80: [180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240],
 90: [100, 110, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240],
 100: [110, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240],
 110: [180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240],
 120: [130, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240],
 130: [180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240],
 140: [150, 160, 165, 180, 200, 190, 210, 220, 230, 240],
 150: [160, 165, 180, 200, 190, 210, 220, 230, 240],
 160: [165, 180, 200, 190, 210, 220, 230, 240],
 165: [180, 200, 190, 210, 200, 220, 230, 240],
 170: [175, 180, 200, 190, 210, 220, 230, 240],
 175: [180, 200, 190, 210, 200, 220, 230, 240],
 180: [190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240],
 190: [200, 210, 220, 230, 240],
 200: [210, 220, 230, 240],
 210: [220, 230, 240],
 220: [230, 240],
 230: [240]}
```

---

EDIT 2: If `df` is your input dataframe with "df1" and "df2" columns:

```
from pprint import pprint

d = dict()
for i, j in zip(df.df1, df.df2):
    if i == j:
        continue
    if j == '-':   # <-- this will remove the `-` character in df2
        continue
    d.setdefault(i, []).append(j)

for k in d:
    seen = set()
    for v in d[k]:
        for val in d.get(v, []):
            if val not in seen:
                seen.add(val)
                d[k].append(val)


df = pd.DataFrame({'df1': list(d.keys()), 'df2': [', '.join(str(v) for v in d[k]) for k in d]})
print(df)
```

Comment: Could you explain how `d[k].extend(chain.from_iterable(d.get(v, []) for v in d[k]))` this works? I looked at the doc, but couldn't follow.

Comment: @sathyz I use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the iterable - in this case, the iterable is consisting of lists from the dictionary `d` (or empty lists, if key`v` doesn't exist in `d` - `d.get(v, [])`). Then I use these values to extend the list stored at `d[k]`.

Comment: @AndrejKesely ```if not (line := line.strip().split()):``` is to say ```if not (line != line.strip().split()):```? or something else. I am getting error with ```:```.  

When I make it ```!=``` I am getting ```IndexError: string index out of range
``` error at line ```df1.append(int(line[1]))```.

Comment: @AndrejKesely, One last question, is there any way to substitute this ```for line in data.splitlines()[:-1]:``` with something else to give the data frame directly. Because when I give the data frame name directly I am getting an error ```AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'splitlines' ``` Hope I am not bothering you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204797/discussion-between-kapital-and-andrej-kesely).

Comment: Your EDIT 2 solution gives exactly the same result as the first solution. The challenge is here 

```
for line in data.splitlines()[:-1]: 
    line = line.strip().split()
    if not line:
        continue

    df1.append(int(line[1]))
    df2.append(int(line[2]))
````

Comment: @Kapital you don't do `.splitlines()` on dataframe. Just use your current dataframe `df` you already have on the script in EDIT 2 (the script is expecting that this dataframe has "df1" and "df2" columns)

Comment: @AndrejKesely, Yes I did but couldn't get the result similar to the 1st EDIT. But the result is the same as the first solution. >> https://imgur.com/KCPt7Ct

Comment: @Kapital You're doing something wrong, the result from the data (as posted in your question) is the same as in my first EDIT. Do you use Jupyter notebook? If yes, reload/restart it... There's no way to obtain this result with my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for the clarification, I have a solution with a recursive function that you can try. May not be efficient for large data frames but seems to work well.
The function returns a list but you can edit the resulting series to join the list into a string however you'd like.

```
def get_related(df1, related):
    # get directly related values
    next_vals = df.loc[df['df1'] == df1, 'df2'].values.tolist()
    # remove links to self (will cause recursion issues)
    next_vals = list(set(next_vals) - set([df1]))
    # add to running list
    related = related + next_vals
    # continue to next level
    if any(next_val in df['df1'].unique() for next_val in next_vals):
        for next_val in next_vals:
            related = related + get_related(next_val, related)
    # get unique list
    return list(set(related))

df['df1'].apply(lambda x: get_related(x, []))
```

Comment: Could you explain what "related" is from the function argument?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```py
def recursive_walk(df, node):
    parents=df.loc[(df['df1']==node) & (df['df2']!=node), 'df2'].tolist()
    if(len(parents)==0):
        yield node
    else:
        for parent in parents:
            yield parent
            lst=[el for el in recursive_walk(df, parent)]
            for el in lst:
                yield el

df['tree']=df.apply(lambda x: list(set([el for el in recursive_walk(df, x['df2'])]+[x['df2']])), axis=1)
```

Output:

```py
   df1  df2                  tree
0   10   20  [40, 50, 20, 90, 30]
1   20   30      [40, 50, 90, 30]
2   30   40              [40, 50]
3   60   80                  [80]
4   70   70             [100, 70]
5   40   50                  [50]
6   30   90                  [90]
7   70  100                 [100]
```

(*) I also checked with extended dataframe - it's pretty fast, I won't share the output, since my IDE is truncating it ;)

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but I was looking at your solution and I couldn't understand what do you mean by ```node``` (one of your parameter in the function)? Could you tell me?

Comment: ```node``` is the value you are currently at. So you return it, and in case it has any parents, different than itself (so called circular reference) you iterate over it's parents, and run same function for them.

Comment: When I just give a random number for the node I am getting something like this. ```<generator object recursive_walk at 0x0000022A67551D48>```.  Which is I don know what it means.

Comment: Try: ```list(recursive_walk(...))``` or ```[el for el in recursive_walk(...)]``` function returns ```generator``` - which essentially means- not all elements at once like e.g. ```list``` or ```tuple``` but provides iterable that you can use to return all values one by one.